# PHP: Only showing 1 match when 2 exists

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($show["status"]);
if (preg_match("#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#", $content, $matches)) {
  foreach(array_unique($matches) as $m) {
?><a id="<?php echo $m; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="fancybox_vid"><img src="images/icons/youtube.png" style="margin-right: 4px;"></a><?php
  }
}
echo $content;
```

Right now if there exists 2 links in $content, it will only make  1 anchor+imageicon, but I want it to then make two anchor+imageicon? What is wrong and how can i fix this?

I tried remove the array_unique, made no difference.

Comment: Can you give an example `$content` string for which you expect it to work but it doesn't?

Comment: Why are you processing it with `array_unique()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Comment: @Karem: Take a look at the [docs](http://php.net/preg_match_all). The `$matches` structure is different for `preg_match_all()`. `array_unique()` is probably not doing what you intended, here.

Comment: @Karem: Try passing the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag.

Comment: @elusive @JonahBron I removed array_unique, and add PREG_SET_ORDER. But the value of $m now is "Array", how can I fix this last thing?

Comment: @Karem: The value is not `Array`. You should check the value with `var_dump()` or `print_r()` (how do you debug without these two functions, anyway?). The docs give plenty of usage examples and describe the structure of the array in detail.

Comment: @elusive yes I did try print_r $m inside the foreach, and the values are there that i want in id="", but how do I use them out from there? I have it inside a foreach shouldnt that be it?